# Docker: Difference between `docker run` and `docker service`

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am very new to `docker` , just started venturing into this. I read online about this. I came to know of the following commands of `docker` which is: `docker run` and `docker service`. As I understood , with `docker run` we are spinning a new `container`. However I am not clear what `docker service` do? Does it spin container in a `Swarm`?

Can anyone help understand in simple to understand?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `docker run` command creates and starts a container on the local docker host.

A docker "service" is one or more containers with the same configuration running under docker's swarm mode. It's similar to `docker run` in that you spin up a container. The difference is that you now have orchestration. That orchestration restarts your container if it stops, finds the appropriate node to run the container on based on your constraints, scale your service up or down, allows you to use the mesh networking and a VIP to discover your service, and perform rolling updates to minimize the risk of an outage during a change to your running application.

Answer (score 11):

**Docker Run vs Docker service**

`docker run`:

> we can create number of containers with different images.

`docker service`:

> we can create number of containers with same image in a single command line.

SYNTAX:

```
docker service create --name service-name --network network-name --replicas number-of-containers image-name
```

EXAMPLE:

```
docker service create --name service1 --network swarm-net --replicas 5 redis
```